# Import Python lib in C#

Tags: c#, python, import

There is an existing python lib which i have to instantiate in my C# code.
Which is the best possible way to do so? And how?
I am not much familiar with python, so IronPython, py2exe confused me big time.
Please Help.

Answer (score 4):

You'll almost certainly be better off finding a C#/.NET alternative to that library. What is it?

If you do really need to do this your best option will be IronPython. There are a few guides to embedding IronPython code in C#, such as [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Call_ironpython__in_C_.aspx).